# Is it possible to bind multiple fixed pages in a FixedDocument?

Tags: wpf, xps, fixeddocument

To produce an `XPS` document you can write `XAML` that looks something like this:

```
<FixedDocument>
  <PageContent>
    <FixedPage>
       <!-- Page content -->
    </FixedPage>
  </PageContent>
</FixedDocument>
```

I want my `XPS` to contain a *collection of fixed pages*. How can I bind to a collection to get multiple pages inside my document? As far as I know, I cannot use the `FlowDocument` as it lays out the pages dynamically. There is very limited information regarding this on the internet.

Ideally, I would have something like an `ItemsControl` and bind to a page template. That way, I could add N items to the list and get N pages.

Comment: Are you going to be using a FixedDocument Template for the databinding?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but no, I don't think so. Only simple data will be bound for each page.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar but with a predefined template for the databinding to. See http://www.bradcurtis.com/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-data-binding-and-xps/

Comment: Curtis' work was my starting point. I ended up adding my pages in code-behind. Hence, the template is applied for one `FixedPage` at a time.